# Should I draw or load an image?

Tags: android

I am wondering what would be the best practice for android. To draw or to load an image?
For example I want to have a circle that is green filled with the text 25 in it. 
-Should I have it in .PNG image file and just load it to the imageview placeholder when I need it? 
OR should I load it in Java (by determining the position in java and load it from my res folder)?

OR Should I draw it  (draw a circle, fill color, add text field inside)?

On another note, to have a checkmark, what do advise me to do?I don't even know how to draw that

I really need your help in this
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually argue that there is a single right answer. You should use a shape with a set color and text view inside it. It is easy to do what you've described in xml, see: [Oval Gradient in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527567/oval-gradient-in-android) for an example (there are a number if you google for android shapes). This will be less CPU/memory intensive than loading a bitmap, and more importantly, it will work for and look good on every screen size. As an added bonus of the user has changed their default font sizes, a textView/shape can respect that and a static image can not. Just set the background of your TextView to be the shape drawable (either in xml or programatically).

To get a bitmap to look good on multiple devices (a must for android development) , you will need a number of different versions of the same bitmap at different resolutions (XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI... etc).

Check marks are harder because they don't conform to a standard shape. Those you probably will have to make pngs for.

Comment: Thank you for answer and I think a direct answer is what I am looking for. However when I said draw, I didn't mean draw it from bitmap. I meant actualy drawing circles in Java (kinda like paint functionality). So I am not suree which one is better. I never new about shapes existance in xml for android. I will check it out. Is this available for 2.1?

Comment: ShapeDrawables have existed since the first version http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html

Comment: So I can create and xml that has the shape I want, Then I can add a text view in the layout XML file with the shape as my my backgorund drawble, right? No java involved in here, Good. If thats the case, one more thing Monkeyless, I want this shape (with the text) hidden until the user clicks something. How can I make this shape/text hidden at first? I prefer in XML but if not how I can make it hidden in code.THANK YOU

Comment: Oh btw, if someone changes the font size then the text can get bigger than Oval since it is set as background, right?

Comment: Yup exactly. Create the shape you want in xml. Then in your layout, set that shape (@drawable/name_of_your_shape_file) to be the background of whatever text view you want to show the numbers. To change the visibility on click, you will need to use java (the simplest way is to add an on click listener to the view in onCreate of your activity), but you can specify the initial visibility using android:visibility. And yes if the font size changes, the background will expand to match it (keep in mind if you want a perfect circle, ovals may just expand sideways)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do.

Rendering a bitmap will be faster, but you cannot manipulate it after it is drawn.

So, for your case, you have a green circle with 25 written it.  Do you also need a green ball with 23 and another with 24 in it?  What about other colors?

It really depends on the amount of variation you need.  At a certain point the overhead of using dozens of images will not be worth the evert of drawing to a canvas.  Or, depending on how complex the images are, it will be.

The question is not "Which is better?", but instead, "Which is better for what I need to do?"

Comment: thank you for answer.. kinda confused me more but good to know the details that I need to bring when asking next time

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Android development but after seeing your question I have done a bit of reading and came across this article on **displaying images with android** that is relevant and includes some code to possibly help you out. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-displaying.html

As for your image of a check mark, why dont you just go into photoshop or paint and use the line tool to draw a checkmark and then fill it in with color and save it as a .png perhaps?

Comment: I like your links and definitly helpful to check. Thumbs up for answer