# Android: How to make a gradient image that focus on center

Tags: android, gradient, android-xml

[image]

How do I make a gradient image in Android, like this photo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527567/oval-gradient-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this, Hope it will work for you

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250"
        android:startColor="#E9E9E9" android:endColor="#D4D4D4" />
</shape>
```